# Object is possible undefined but check is present?

Tags: typescript

I am pretty confident that the check is in place, however, I don't know why the typescript checker says otherwise. Is it because of using the `[]` notation?

```
export const getSingleQueryStringParameter = (queryObject: ParsedUrlQuery, value: string, defaultValue: any = null) => {
  if (Array.isArray(queryObject[value]) && queryObject[value][0]) {   /// queryObject[value][0] (value is possible undefined)
    return queryObject[value][0];
  }

  if (queryObject[value]) {
    return queryObject[value];
  }

  return defaultValue;
};
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that others can paste into their own IDEs to see the issue you're having.  In this case you should either declare `ParsedUrlQuery` or, even better, replace it with something native to TypeScript.

Comment: @jcalz ParsedUrlQuery comes from node.

Comment: So then could you [edit] to declare it like `import { ParsedUrlQuery } from 'querystring';` or whatever you need to do so that standalone IDEs can access it?   Or tag the question as depending on node?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is due to a bug in typescript accessing the values with `[]` as I've refactored it extracting the value and the error is gone.

```
export const getSingleQueryStringParameter = (queryObject: ParsedUrlQuery, key: string, defaultValue: any = null) => {
  const value = queryObject[key];

  if (Array.isArray(value) && value[0]) {
    return value[0];
  }

  if (value) {
    return value;
  }

  return defaultValue;
};
```

Comment: The relevant issue is being tracked at [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530); the recommended workaround is indeed to copy before guarding, as you're doing here.